Color inversion while increasing zoom level while plotting polygon string with Bing Maps API key in python
I want to increase zoom level of plot consisting of polygon plotted using matplotlib library on Bing Maps. I am using the following code:
import requests
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('default')
# matplotlib.use('Agg')
API_KEY = "<api key"
poly_str = [(26.258654470488352, 50.60623948760518), (26.260892838025025, 50.61137614053575), (26.259367564324837, 50.612537537528866), (26.257912032768143, 50.615014721155816), (26.257639268464615, 50.60718484036582)]

# Coordinates for the center of the map
center_lat1 = sum([coord[0] for coord in poly_str])
center_lon1 = sum([coord[1] for coord in poly_str])
center_lat = center_lat1/len(poly_str)
center_lon = center_lon1/len(poly_str)
print(f"Centroid Latitude: {center_lat}")
print(f"Centroid Longitude: {center_lon}")

# Static map parameters
zoom_level = 16
map_size = '4000,4000'

# Bing Maps API URL
map_url = f"http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Imagery/Map/Road/{center_lat},{center_lon}/{zoom_level}?mapSize={map_size}&format=png&key={API_KEY}"

# Fetch the static map image
response = requests.get(map_url)
image = Image.open(BytesIO(response.content))

# Display the map using matplotlib
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8),dpi=200)
ax.imshow(np.asarray(image), extent=[0, image.width, 0, image.height])

polygon_coords =[(841, 678), (1086, 665), (1084, 573), (1006, 471), (866, 586)]
print(polygon_coords)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
# plt.savefig("map_bing.jpg")

On putting zoom_level = 15, I am getting the following image:

As soon as I change zoom_level = 16 or more, I get the following image:

How do I keep the background colour constant while changing the zoom level?

Don't include common salutation like please and thanks in your post. Consider these guidelines No Thanks, Damn It!.

Noted, any suggestions from your side for resolving the background issue?

Definately odd. All I can say is I've never seen the Bing Maps imagery service ever do this, so it's most likely something to do with the tools that are drawing the polygon on the image afterwards. Note that Bing Maps is being retired: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/bing-maps They are recommending moving to Azure Maps. With Azure Maps you can have simple polygons like this drawn on the image in that single call to the imagery service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-render-custom-data#render-a-polygon-with-color-and-opacity

@SharvariMittal no. I came across this item in the staging ground so I was reviewing the suitability of the post not attempting to solve the problem.

@rbrundritt I am using the library matplotlib for creating the polygon so maybe that's causing the issue?
All I want to know is, how can I fix this?

I resolved the issue by checking the mode of the image received by the bing map url, and using the following code for resolution -
print(image.mode) #giving P
if image.mode != 'RGB':
image = image.convert('RGB')

@SharvariMittal you should post the solution as a self-answer to the question instead of putting it in the comments.

@bad_coder I dont have the option of adding the answer to questions yet
